# Use a Router to connect 2 subnetworks

Tags: networking, router, lan, iis, asp.net

I created an IIS server for an asp.net application in one of my job PCs. This PC is connected to the main LAN, and has a static IP (ex. `10.138.1.92`).

Beside, I need to connect a Switch with 3 PCs to it that are not connected to the main LAN, with the purpose to bring access to the application to them.

I configured the 3 PCs like a private LAN:

```
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13
```

I read that using the NAT of one router I can connect 2 subnetworks.
**Can I connect my switch to one router, this router to the server PC, and make accessible the application?**

I need something like: `192.168.1.11 >> 10.158.1.92:8080/Login.aspx`

I really would appreciate your help.

Here's the network in Packet Tracer image":

[image]

What I have to add and configure to access from PC0 to WebServer web?? I can translate it later IRL.

Comment: The router needs to know about both subnets, and needs to be configured to route traffic between them as needed.

Comment: But it is possible to do what I want with the router??

Comment: Yes, if it is properly configured

Comment: It difinitely possible, but way depends on available features of Your router model. So which router You like to use? Using NAT is unnecessary in this scenario, but many cheap home NAT routers make NAT unavoidable in configuration.

Comment: Here's the network in Packet Tracer [Image](http://oi63.tinypic.com/ra14xe.jpg) . What I have to add and configure to access from PC0 to WebServer web?? I can translate it later IRL. @MikhailMoskalev

Answer (score 0):

> I read that using the NAT of one router I can connect 2 subnetworks.

Not with the sort of standard NAT most home routers come by default.

With this kind of NAT, you can connect your "private" network of 3 PCs (on the "LAN" ports) to the other network of your asp.net application (on the WAN port), and **outgoing** requests from your 3 PCs to the asp.net application will get NATed.

But it doesn't work the other way round. As home routers normally have multiple LAN ports (i.e., an in-built switch), you don't need any additional switch. Just connect the 3 PCs directly to the home router.

Alternative solutions:

1) Don't use a a router, use the switch to directly connect the 3 PCs, give the 3 PCs static or dynamic 10.138.1.*/24 addresses.

2) Use a router without NAT (or use a professional grade switch with routing features). Give the 3 PCs 192.168.1.* addresses, and **set routes on all hosts which need to access the other subnet** to the gateway address(es) of the router. This is the standard for routing between subnets, but it's difficult to do on home routers, and a way to distribute routes automatically (DHCP) is preferred. You do need to understand more details about networking for this solution.